# Const converting std containers

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider that I have a std::vector.

```
std::vector<int> blah;
blah.push_back(1);
blah.push_back(2);
```

I now want to pass the vector somewhere and disallow modifying the contents of the objects its contains while still allowing to modify the container when able:

```
// Acceptable use:
void call_something() {
    std::vector<int> blah;
    blah.push_back(1);
    blah.push_back(2);

    // Currently, compiler error because of mismatching types
    something(blah);
}

void something(std::vector<const int>& blah)
{
    // Auto translates to 'const int'
    for ( auto& i : blah ) {
        // User cannot modify i.
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    blah.push_back(blah.size()); // This should be acceptable
    blah.emplace_back(); // This should be acceptable
    return;
}

// Unacceptable use:
void something_else(const std::vector<int>& blah)
{
    // Because of const vector, auto translates to 'const int'
    for ( auto& i : blah ) {
        std::cout << i std::endl;
    }
    blah.push_back(blah.size()); // This will present an unacceptable compiler error.
    blah.emplace_back(); // This will present an unacceptable compiler error.
    return;
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps if you encapsulate it..

Comment: Are you saying you want `push_back` to be allowed within `something_else`? Also I'm assuming you meant `for ( auto& i : blah )` in `something_else` since the `for` you have right now doesn't actually modify any of the vector elements. Finally, what's to stop me from `erase + insert` a new element into the `vector` if I'm still able to modify the container?

Comment: @Praetorian: The internal shuffling won't work. ;) You'd only be able to do this to the last one.

Comment: Yes, I would like to still be able to `push_back` any new objects (or even potentially default-create, even if I can't subsequently modify the default-created object). Modifying (erasing and inserting) should cause compile errors regarding const-ness.

Comment: What's the real problem you are looking for a solution to?

Comment: @RSahu I somewhat fear lamentations from addressing the very same question.

Comment: You could pass a back insert iterator to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the operations you wish to allow while preventing the others, you need to take a fine-grained approach to your function's interface. For example, if your calling code were to pass const iterators (begin and end) as well as a back inserter (or custom back emplacer functor), then exactly the subset of operations you showed would be possible.

```
template <class Iter, class F>
void something(Iter begin, Iter end, F&& append)
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<value_type>(std::cout, "\n"));
    append(std::distance(begin, end));
    append();
    return;
}
```

That said I don't find your examples particularly compelling. Do you have a real scenario in which you must maintain mutable elements, pass a mutable container to a function, yet treat the passed elements as immutable?

Comment: I would say that the elements are immutable. Do I have a real scenario for this? No; my actual problem was resolved with a const container (don't need to modify the container in the callback). However, the problem I was working on spawned this question in my head. So this is more an academic question just to learn more about the language.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *easy* way to do this. One way would be to wrap a `vector` in a type that exposes only the functionality that you want to allow. For instance

```
template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
struct vector_wrap
{
    using iterator = typename std::vector<T, A>::const_iterator;
    using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T, A>::const_iterator;
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T, A>::size_type;

    vector_wrap(std::vector<T, A>& vec)
    : vec_(&vec)
    {}

    void push_back(T const& value) { vec_->push_back(value); }
    void push_back(T&& value) { vec_->push_back(std::move(value)); }
    size_type size() { return vec_->size(); }
    iterator begin() const { return vec_->cbegin(); }
    iterator end() const { return vec_->cend(); }

private:
    std::vector<T, A> *vec_;
};
```

Since the above implementation only stores a pointer to the `vector` it wraps, you'll have to ensure that the lifetime of the `vector` is longer than that of `vector_wrap`.

You'll have to modify `something` and `something_else` so that they take a `vector_wrap<int>` as argument. Since `vector_wrap::begin` and `vector_wrap::end` return `const_iterator`s, you'll not be allowed to modify existing elements within the `for` statement.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9710673a49406975)

Comment: This is pretty nifty. However, I think I like the answer @michael-urman (holy crap how do I get the @ to work on his name?) gave better since it doesn't directly require creating a new type.

Comment: @inetknght (just skip the space?) To be fair, to use the exact code I showed, you need a custom back-emplacer type, or `append()` won't work. I don't think there's a globally better choice between these two approaches, so keep them both in your tool box, and apply whichever's locally better.